# Which program can be used to create references with bullet points like these?

Tags: formatting

This seems to be created using a program, maybe Adobe Acrobat?

Look at http://elsa.berkeley.edu/~sdellavi/wp/FieldExperimentJEPPublished.pdf

Starting from page 56 (at the bottom), you can see that the blue bullet points for the references are clickable. I have seen this exact same formatting for another academic at another university, so I believe it's a common software.

Does anyone know what the software to make these  nicely formatted bullets are?

Comment: Have you tried looking at LateX and Acrobat, the usual suspects?

Comment: The blue bullet characters don't do anything for me when I click them, but they do change from blue to orange as I mouse over them.  They act like clickable links for you?  Do they open a browser page?

Comment: The PDF's properties say that it was created using [Atypon](http://www.atypon.com)'s PDF Plus solution.

Answer (score 1):

Links in PDF files can be created using the hyperref package for LaTeX, which also enables internal links for references, the index etc.